Compatible Replacement for Shimano Tiagra RD-4500GS?
I have an old bicycle Cube Peloton 2010 with a  Shimano Tiagra RD-4500GS rear derailleur.
What modern rear derailleur can be fitted to this bike without any problems?

The Tiagra 4500 model is a 9 speed rear system. So one can say your RD-4500 is a 9 speed rear derailleur.  The GS signifies it has a medium length cage, and that implies it can be used on a bike with triple chainrings up front because the longer cage has more chain wrap capacity.  More capacity is needed in a triple chainrings set up because there is larger difference in tooth count between the large ring and small ring of a triple than there would be for a double (aka 2x, two-by) front system.  Thus, one aspect of a new derailleur is having a medium or long cage imbuing the derailleur with adequate capacity for your set-up.
Here's the short answer: the newest Shimano road 9 speed system is termed "Sora," and the rear derailleur for it carries the model number:    RD-R3000 and comes in either the SS or GS cage length.  Another new model is the Claris, RD-R2000.  Claris is Shimano's 8 speed road system but the rear der will work perfectly in your 9 speed system. You are not limited to these two  derailleur models, however. Read on to learn why.
The selection of rear ders that will function exactly the same in your system include ALL Shimano rear derailleurs marketed as 7, 8, or 9 speed (this includes both road and mountain bike categories), as well as 10 speed road derailleurs.*
*Ironically, today's newest Tiagra system  (R4700), is a ten speed road group. However, the rear derailleur is engineered in such a way that doesn't allow it to be used like the above mentioned classes of derailleurs.
In other words, you could purchase a Shimano Alivo mountain bike rear derailleur (RD-M4000), a 9 speed mountain derailleur, install it on your bike and given the correct, standard set-up any rear derailleur would require is completed, shifting would be normal. The same as if you installed the Sora instead.
So, the fact that all these speed classes of Shimano rear derailleurs are essentially interchangable (given other specs like the appropriate length cage are considered), gives you a wide variety of fully compatible options. There is quite a selection of gently used and even NOS (New Old Stock) offerings on sites like eBay and Facebook marketplace.

Nice answer - I'd also recommend changing the gear cable inner, and ideally the outer as well.

I completely agree. Especially considering the chief cause of poor shifting is excess friction directly related to a problem in the cabling..
